# Which Stack Exchange site for a question about mobile cloud backend solutions and licensing

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question on Mobile Cloud backend solutions and mobile app licensing. I've tried Stack Overflow and Super User and the questions have been closed. Please can you tell me which site is best for these?

Comment: Why were they closed ? Can you post a link to these questions ? Maybe it's just the way you asked them.

Comment: Just curious - what's the downvote about?  This seems like a valid question, being asked in the right place, with NO ranting or venting about questions being closed.

Answer (score 9):

### Short Answer

> Which Stack Exchange site to use for this question

None. Shopping questions don't fit the Q&A standards of Stack Exchange.

### Long Answer

I will imply this is [the question you're talking about.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751080/mobile-apps-per-user-licensing)

It was closed as not constructive as explained under the question :

[image]

Which is good news for you since it wasn't closed as **off topic**. You were in the right place but didn't ask the *right question* or didn't ask the *right way*. You can't simply ask for such a solution on Stack Overflow. **But**, on your way of doing this :

> So we need to set up a licensing server to check number of users using the app.

If you encounter a specific problem, you can always come here, show what you've tried and what failed, provide some code and get the desired support.

You should refer to the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) to know how to ask a good question that fits the site's standards.

Comment: Looks like a shopping question, so no, there is no appropriate SE site.

Comment: @Wooble Thanks. Edited with this in mind ^.^

Comment: Of course, there's now [softwarerecs.se], so there might be a place for this after all.